# About VBA extensibility library

Tags: excel, vba

Can we able to insert a break point via VBA code in a module as we can insert a line by passing line number using VBIDE object library? OR is it possible to color the line by passing line number by using the same?

```
Sub AddProcedureToModule()
    Dim VBProj As VBIDE.VBProject
    Dim VBComp As VBIDE.VBComponent
    Dim CodeMod As VBIDE.CodeModule
    Dim LineNum As Long
    Const DQUOTE = """" ' one " character

    Set VBProj = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject
    Set VBComp = VBProj.VBComponents("Module1")
    Set CodeMod = VBComp.CodeModule

    With CodeMod
        LineNum = .CountOfLines + 1
        .InsertLines LineNum, "Public Sub SayHello()"
        LineNum = LineNum + 1
        .InsertLines LineNum, "    MsgBox " & DQUOTE & "Hello World" & DQUOTE
        LineNum = LineNum + 1
        .InsertLines LineNum, "End Sub"
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Coloring a line is not possible - you simply can't do that in the VBE editor.

With a trick, you can set a break point by activate the `CodeModule`, select the line where you want to have the break point and simulate pressing <kbd>F9</kbd>. However, I don't know how reliable this works, and you will get an error message if the line cannot hold a break point (comment lines, Variable definitions, empty lines ...)

```
VBComp.Activate
With VBProj.VBE.ActiveCodePane
    .SetSelection LineNum, 1, LineNum, 1
    SendKeys "{F9}"
End With
```

To select the entire row, use

```
    .SetSelection LineNum, 1, LineNum, Len(CodeMod.Lines(LineNum, 1)) + 1
```

Comment: Actually i have a .json file which contain line number and a word to highlight in that line so i want to write a VBA code for this, as you said it is not possible to color the line in the editor so it is also not possible?

Comment: I don't think so. What's the idea about that anyhow?

Comment: Just i want to highlight the error in code by highlighting all those words.